# Calculating flux for a triangle

Tags: greens-theorem

> Find the flux of $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{F}}=x\boldsymbol{\mathrm{i}} +4y \boldsymbol{\mathrm{j}}$ outwards across the triangle with vertices at $(0,0),(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$.
>
> **Solution:** $10$

The answer says it's $10$, but I calculated it as $20$. I'm pretty sure i did the steps right, unless I have to halve it in the end because it's a triangle? I get double integral both a limits from $0$ to $2$. Integrate with respect to $x$ first we get

$$
\left[5x\right]_{x=2}^{x=0}.
$$

Then it's just limit from $y=0$ to $y=2$ at $10\;\mathrm{d}y = 20$.

Comment: Please learn how to [format formulae properly](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: one of the integration limits will have to have a variable in it, describing the relationship between $x$ and $y$ on the diagonal of the triangle... if $0\le x \le 2$ then $0\le y \le 2-x$

Comment: @TerryLee I wasn't sure what methodologies you wished to use, so I provided an answer using two distinct approaches.  Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**METHOD 1:**

Using the Divergence Theorem we have

$$\int_C \vec F\cdot \hat n d\ell=\int_S \nabla \cdot \vec F dS=\int_S 5 dS=10$$

since $\nabla \cdot \vec F=\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}=1+4=5$ and the area of the triangle is $\frac12 \times 2 \times 2=2$

---

**METHOD 2:**

Here, we integrate the line integral directly.  To that end, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_C\vec F\cdot \hat n d\ell&=\int_0^2 (\hat xx+\hat y\,0)\cdot (-\hat y) dx+\int_0^2 (\hat x2+\hat y4y)\cdot (\hat x) dy+\int_0^2(\hat xt+\hat y4t)\cdot \frac{-\hat x+\hat y}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2}dt\\\\
&=0+4+6\\\\
&=10
\end{align}$$

as expected!